# "Tracking Information Not Found" error with UPS RESTful Integration Testing URI

Tags: json, rest, http, get, ups

I tried to get the result of UPS RESTful API with my valid track number and API key. I get the following error: "TW0001, Tracking Information Not Found". This happens if I use this Integration Testing URI (`https://wwwcie.ups.com/track/v1/details/`). When I replaced it with Production URI, I got track information without any errors:

`https://onlinetools.ups.com/track/v1/details/`.

I don’t think it’s normal, because the Integration Testing URI should have returned valid information, not an error.

My HTTP GET request example:

```
GET https://wwwcie.ups.com/track/v1/details/1ZXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
transId: 12345
transactionSrc: TestTrack
AccessLicenseNumber: MY_KEY
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Username: MY_USERNAME
Password: MY_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to answer, Tracking Numbers for Testing CIE can be found in "Tracking RESTful Developer guide.pdf"

| Type | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Small Package | 1Z5338FF0107231059 | Delivery Attempted |
| Mail Innovations | 92055900100111152280003029 | Activity List |
| Freight | 7798339175 | Activity List |
| Overnight | 572254454 | Delivered |

Comment: Thank you. A year ago, the documentation didn't contain any details.